# pluralize results if plural in symfony (good practice)

Tags: symfony, pluralize

I have a filter bar that let me search some results within my database.

I have a flash message that shows how many results are found when I enter a word inside it.

**this is my controller**

```
 if ($filter != '') {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'worked!');
      }
```

**and this is in my template**

```
{% for message in app.session.flashbag.get('info') %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor %}
```

so when i research things actually, whether I have 1 result or more it doesn't change my sentence.

[image]

[image]

`résultats` is still written with an `s` as it is hard coded. How can I create something that will allow me to pluralize and singularize a word in my template? Should I go directly in the controller for that ?

**EDIT**

I used this method directly in the template but I don't think it is a "good practice" one. Any help for making that better?

```
{{ results.getTotalItemCount }}
{% if results.getTotalItemCount <= 1 %}
   {{ 'this.is.your.result'|trans({ '%count%': results.getTotalItemCount}) }}
{% else %}
   {{ 'this.is.your.results'|trans({ '%count%': results.getTotalItemCount}) }}
{% endif %}
```

in translation

```
this:
    is:
       your.result:    "résultat"
       your.results:   "résultats"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should maybe check pluralization in translations [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#pluralization), you can use [transChoice()](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html#method_transChoice) method, it is explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#pluralization) how to use it.

Here you can see how to use it in twig:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10817495/5258172

**Edit**: 
your answer in question can be done like this:

```
this:
    is:
       your.result: "1 résultat|%count% résultats"
```

and then in your twig:

```
{{ 'this.is.your.result'|transchoice(results.getTotalItemCount) }}
```

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that already, but as a new developer I find it tedious to understand where to place things. But thanks for the infos.

Comment: @chickenburger I edited the answer and provided a link to other SO answer where you can see how to use it and where to place things.

Comment: i succeeded in a different way, see my question.

Comment: @chickenburger I edited my answer with code, how it can be done with `transChoice() ` method.

Comment: hmm there is an error when I apply your code :/ `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to choose a translation for "{1}1 résultat|]1,Inf]%count% résultats" with locale "fr". Double check that this translation has the correct plural options (e.g. "There is one apple|There are %count% apples").")`

Comment: @chickenburger try to add a space to `{1} 1`

Comment: @chickenburger what symfony version are you using?

Comment: Maybe I guess it is because I'm working on a symfony 2.3 project and it doesn't understand transchoice i guess. But your solution might be working well on 2.8 and higher so i'm validating it as it works by tweaking a little bit. Thank you !

Comment: @chickenburger transchoice should work in 2.3 also, I guess it worked?