# How to translate with pluralization and formatting in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I've got a case where I need to translate messages with pluralization and also format the number differently.

Example messages I wish to get in the translation are:

```
No views
1 view
100 views
1 234 567 views
```

Till now I used:

```
{{ variable.count|number_format(0, '.', ' ') }} views
```

I've tried:

```
{{ 'number_of_views'|trans({count: variable.count}) }}
```

but then I get:

```
1,234,567 views
```

instead of

```
1 234 567 views
```

How I can use translation with number_format for the same keyword?

Comment: Result of number_format function is actually string. For pluralization you need number (integer or float). So the answer is "no". But you should take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/master/translation/message_format.html#numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to translate with pluralization in Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384745/how-to-translate-with-pluralization-in-twig)